# ulTaskNotifyTake() not blocking after xTaskNotifyStateClear()

Tags: freertos

The official FreeRTOS docs give an example on how to clear a task's notification state with `xTaskNotifyStateClear()` before waiting for a notification with `ulTaskNotifyTake()` to make sure `ulTaskNotifyTake()` doesn't return instantly due to previous notification: https://www.freertos.org/xTaskNotifyStateClear.html

In short:

```
xTaskNotifyStateClear(NULL);
ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY); // Should block according to example
```

When I tried this in my code, `ulTaskNotifyTake()` returned immediately, though. After reading the function's docs (https://www.freertos.org/ulTaskNotifyTake.html), I think it does so because `xTaskNotifyStateClear(NULL)` only clears the current task's notification status but not the notification value and `ulTaskNotifyTake()` only looks for the latter. The following code works for me and confirms my assumption:

```
xTaskNotifyStateClear(NULL);
ulTaskNotifyValueClear(NULL, UINT_MAX);
ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY); // Does block
```

Is my understanding, that `ulTaskNotifyTake()` doesn't block as long as the notification value is greater 0 correct? Is the official example (https://www.freertos.org/xTaskNotifyStateClear.html) incorrect then, as the call to `xTaskNotifyStateClear()` doesn't guarantee `ulTaskNotifyTake()` to block? Should you use `ulTaskNotifyValueClear()` or `xTaskNotifyWait()` in the example, instead?